# How do I find a variable in NODEJS

Tags: node.js, variables

Good day,

I am trying to read a variable from a process. With javascript, I know, you can use `console.log(window['variable-name'])` to find a variable's contents using a string.

However, for NodeJs, I know you can use `console.log(global['variable-name'])`, but the variable needs to be global, how can I read module local variables?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: only by exporting them (`module.exports.your_var = your_var`) or by setting the variable on `global` (`global.your_var = your_var`).

Longer answer:
Modules, when loaded by Node.js, are being wrapped within a Javascript function and then called when `require`d the first time. Function variables belong to the function's scope and they are unaccessible from outside.

Comment: So because the module is run from the outside, you cannot read it's variables, unless they are global?

Comment: unless the module exports it, I don't know a way you could..

Comment: Interesting, I will just write a comment to just use global on the variable I want to pass to a function via string hahaha XD